# Limit state design/ LRFD of short steel columns

Tags: structural-engineering, design, stresses, plastic

Why do we use the yield strength as the limiting strength in short column design when using limit state design.
Why is the full capacity of the material not utilized (as is the case with beams when we compute plastic moments that occur beyond the yield).